# HTML5 Audio Player : Pause not working

Tags: jquery, html, audio

can you please help me this code? I'm creating an audio player and this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#play").bind("click", function () {
    $("#audio-player")[0].play();
    $(this).attr('id', 'pause-bt');
  })

  $("#pause-bt").live({
    click: function () {
        $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
        $(this).attr('id', 'play');
    }
  })
})
```

I'm using jquery live and bind but both of them doesn't work.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Hey Omar, thanks for your reply. I think I've downloaded the latest version of jquery at their website. Any here's mine : jquery-1.10.1.min.js. Thanks

Comment: then try this `$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#play").on("click", function () {
        $("#audio-player")[0].play();
        $(this).attr('id', 'pause-bt');
    });
    $("#pause-bt").on('click', function () {
        $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
        $(this).attr('id', 'play');
    });
});`

Comment: Thanks Omar, it works but I am using only one ID which is the default attribute value is "play" and when it clicked it will changed the default id value into "pause-bt". And when the pause-bt clicked, it will also change its default id value into "play". Hope it helps ;) Your codes works if the selectors are separated.

Comment: Ok, try this then `$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", '#play', function () {
        $("#audio-player")[0].play();
        $(this).attr('id', 'pause-bt');
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#pause-bt', function () {
        $("#audio-player")[0].pause();
        $(this).attr('id', 'play');
    });
});`

Comment: you nailed it Omar, thanks man...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Omar : https://stackoverflow.com/users/1771795/omar

Code Solved by Omar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
       $(document).on("click", '#play', function () { $("#audio-player")[0].play(); $(this).attr('id', 'pause-bt'); }); 
       $(document).on('click', '#pause-bt', function () { $("#audio-player")[0].pause(); $(this).attr('id', 'play'); }); 
    });
</script>
```

Problem Soved...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest use the HTML5 audio tag if you want to go with HTML5. It will give you player in your browser. Herby I am attaching fiddle of this.

HTML5 Audio Player (jsfiddle.net/L5wRh/126/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.stop').on('click', function(){
    document.getElementById("videocontainer").pause();  
  });
});
```

```html
 <video id="videocontainer" width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="vid/Kuwait_City.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video> 

<a href="#" class="stop">stop</a>
```